# importing jax fails on mac with m1 chip

Tags: python, python-3.8, apple-m1, jax

For python 3.8.8 and using the new mac air (with the m1 chip), in jupyter notebooks and in python terminal, `import jax` raises this error

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/steve/Documents/code/jax/jax/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import config as _config_module
  File "/Users/steve/Documents/code/jax/jax/config.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jax._src.config import config
  File "/Users/steve/Documents/code/jax/jax/_src/config.py", line 26, in <module>
    from jax import lib
  File "/Users/steve/Documents/code/jax/jax/lib/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    cpu_feature_guard.check_cpu_features()
RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. You may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.
```

I suspect it occurs because of the m1 chip.

I tried using jax with `pip install jax`, then I built it from source as suggested by the comment, by cloning their repository and following the instructions given [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#building-from-source), but the same error message shows.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. Since I already had Anaconda installed and didn't want to clutter up my space with Anaconda + miniconda + homebrew versions of python and package management and whatever, I hunted around for a simple solution. What ended up working for me was first uninstalling `jax` and `jaxlib` and then installing `jax` and `jaxlib` via conda-forge directly:

```
pip uninstall jax jaxlib
conda install -c conda-forge jaxlib
conda install -c conda-forge jax
```

Comment: not the point of the question, but are you able to use with `trax` or were you looking to use just `jax`?

Comment: I was just looking at `jax`. hadn't looked at `trax`.

Comment: @NicholasGReich, was just looking for an answer to this exact question, small world.

Comment: Is there a non-conda solution? I want to be able to install to a virtualenv created via `virtualenv` (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks [@jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2937831/jakevdp) I looked at the issue you linked and found a workaround :

Thanks to [Noah](https://github.com/Noahyt?tab=overview&from=2021-07-01&to=2021-07-12) who mentioned in [issue #5501](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/5501) that you could just use a previous version of jax and jaxlib, for my purposes `jaxlib==0.1.60` and `jax==0.2.10` work just fine!

Comment: `jax` is now available for M1 macs; runs fine for me

Comment: True, @emil. Confirmation here: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/5501#issuecomment-955590288 - unclear when next release is, but at least it can be installed now somewhat officially

Answer (score 2):

JAX does not yet provide pre-built jaxlib wheels that are compatible with M1 chips. The best source of information I know on building jaxlib on M1 is probably this github issue: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/5501, which also tracks improving this support.

Hopefully M1 support will be improved in the near future, but it's taking a while for the scientific computing infrastructure up and down the stack to catch up with the requirements of the new chips.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (January 2022), `jax` is available for M1 Macs. Make sure to uninstall `jax` and `jaxlib` and then install the new packages via pip:

`pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib`

Afterwards, you can use jax without problems.

--Edit--
I am running on a machine with the following specs:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.1
BuildVersion:   21C52
```

and with `Python 3.9.6` within a `conda` environment.

Comment: What MacOS and python versions are you using?

Comment: @Blade, I have updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: up to a certain point. I still get this error after uninstalling both `jax` and `jaxlib`, installing with `pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib` and then trying to use it as part of Trax: `RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. You may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.` Same OS version and build, python 3.9.7 within a conda environment.

Comment: @arturomp see my answer that I just posted. I fixed this on my machine by installing from conda-forge directly.

Comment: thank you! I think I did something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815865/