# Can anyone give me a comprehensive guide to installing tensorflow-federated on M1 Mac?

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1, tensorflow-federated

i followed the instructions given by the official tf documentation, but i just cannot resolve the various problems encountered.
Did anyone have the experience installing tff on m1 mac and can show me your overall process?

```
conda create -n federated python=3.8


conda activate federated

pip install --upgrade tensorflow_federated
```

everything seems to be fine according to the terminal output, however,
after

```
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```

i got a RunTimeError:

```
RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. You may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you share what error messages you got?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68345659/14290681) similar resolved issue to fix this `RuntimeError`.

Comment: How to solve the dependency conflict occurred??

Answer (score 0):

Install miniforge with [Apple's arm64: Apple Silicon Method](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/). Then, put it where Anaconda places its initialization code, that is in `~/zshrc`.

This would make miniforge the default manager. Following which you need to create a `~/.start_anaconda.sh` script so that Anaconda can be used as an alternative.

With miniforge,

- Create a new conda environment `mytraxenv` with `conda create -n mytraxenv python=3` which has your python version.
- Activate the environment with `conda activate mytraxenv`
- run `conda install numpy` and `conda install six` to ensure `numpy.six` and `wheel` in `mytraxenv` environment.
- Then `pip install -U pip pip install -U`

Lastly follow these [instructions](https://github.com/google/jax#installation) to install
`pip install --upgrade pip`
`pip install --upgrade "jax[cpu]"`